# Eclipse - exclude file / folder from triggering workspace refresh after build

Tags: java, eclipse, build, workspace

I have a custom builder (batch file) in my Eclipse project that increments the build number and outputs it in a text file in the workspace. This works fine when I build manually. But when automatic building is enabled, the updated build-number file causes Eclipse to refresh the workspace and start a new build, leading to an infinite loop of building.

How can I exclude this build-number file from triggering a rebuild? It's in the WebContent folder, so it's not part of the build path. I've tried the exclusion options I could find, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to mark the file as derived (in the file properties)?

Comment: Why does modifying this text file trigger a build?

Comment: Thanks Jonah, but it didn't work.

Comment: No idea nitind. Isn't this normal behavior? As far as I know, any change to a file triggers automatic rebuilding.

Comment: Hmm. It seems I found a working solution. Enabling 'refresh the entire workspace upon completion' in Builders > Edit > Refresh looks like it doesn't create an infinite loop. I'm gonna give it a try during a workday to see if it performs stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling 'refresh the entire workspace upon completion' in Builders > Edit > Refresh doesn't create this infinite loop.